# add data to elastic using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, elasticsearch

I am working in a project where to search from firebase data using elastic search and trying to  add data to elastic using angularjs but giving error as :

```
{"data":"","status":0,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],
```

my code is:

```
var inputJson =
{
    "mappings": {
        "carprev": {
            "properties": {
                "agepolicy33": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "aircondition33": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "year33": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var corsHeaders = {
origin: ["*"],
headers: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', { 'Content-Type': 
 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }],
credentials: true,
additionalHeaders: ['access-control-allow-headers', 'Access-Control-
Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, CORRELATION_ID'],
additionalExposedHeaders: ['access-control-allow-headers', 'Access-
 Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-
 Requested-With, Content-Type, CORRELATION_ID']
 };

$http({
method: "PUT",
// headers: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type'],
url: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/elasticsearch/test/5",
data: inputJson
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
console.log(response);
}, function myError(err) {
var cjson = JSON.stringify(err);
console.log(err);
});
```

but the same json in inserted into elasticsearch using postman and query data to retrieve from elastic

if anyone can resolve, appreciated

Comment: can you change the content-type to json ('Content-Type': 
 'application/json')?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the content type to json.

```
$http({
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    url: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/elasticsearch/test/5",
    data: inputJson
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
    }, function myError(err) {
    var cjson = JSON.stringify(err);
    console.log(err);
});
```